# How to deal with non fixed springs?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

In every physics book they explain how to compute the force that a spring exert if one of its ends is fixed to a wall (or equivalent) and the other end is compressed or stretched.

But how to deal with the problem if both ends are 'free'.

For example, suppose you have two blocks attached with a spring, and someone apply an horizontal force of, say, 50N. (Lets suppose that there is no friction with the surface, the blocks are originally at rest, the spring is originally in its relaxed state, and the spring constant is, say, 300N/m).

How you would compute the acceleration of each block?

[image]

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: First of all, I don't know if the Hooke's law applies here. If yes, it means that the force exerted on each end is F=-k.d ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several principles you can use here.

1. Remember Hooke's law, $|F|=k |x|$. I've put absolute values around so that we can worry about the direction of the force later.
2. The spring is idealized as massless and so its extension is only to be defined by the positions of the walls of blocks A and B.
3. Each action has an equal and opposite reaction. (except for the "applied" force, whose reaction we are disregarding)

We know that if the spring is extended past equilibrium A and B will be pulled towards each other, and if the spring is squished away from equilibrum then A and B will be pushed apart.

We wind up with the equations: 
$$F_A=m_A a_A=F_0+k x$$
$$F_B=m_B a_B=-k x$$
where I have defined "x" with the sign convention that it is positive when the spring is overextended and negative when the spring is squished. It is also a function of the distance between blocks A and B. If we wanted to find the dynamics of the system, we'd have to do some differential equation stuff, because the accelerations of B and A would be functions of time.

To find *the* accelerations of A and B we'd have to assume the system is in equilibrium. If $x$ is not changing, the velocities of A and B are always the same and so the accelerations of A and B are the same. We wind up with the equations: 
$$m_A a=F_0+k x$$
$$m_B a=-k x$$
which can be solve for for $a$ and $x$ exactly and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

The spring force is a function (linear or not) of the end point deflection. If the two ends have coordinates $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively then the force is $F_S = -K(x_2-x_1)$

This force is applied in equal but opposite terms on both sides of the spring. So one mass sees $F_S$ and the other $-F_S$. Altogether if your positive and negative directions are consistent then you can come up with the equations of motion.

Oh, and look up what a [Free Body Diagram](http://physics.bu.edu/~erikl/Subject_Forces.pdf) is for details on how to deal with such problems.